# Getting into Android with broken screen

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen

My Moto Z Play died during a failed repair attempt.

The digitizer was dead immediately, the screen first still showed a faint image, but that's gone as well now.

ADB is activated, but only after login, and login only works using the gesture, not using the fingerprint sensor, at least after the phone rebooted.

I got scrcpy to work before, but while ADB isn't running, I can't use that.

My phone doesn't have any video output capabilities over it's USB C port, at least none that I ever got to work.

I can connect a mouse to unlock the screen, but without the ability to see the mouse pointer, that doesn't help either.

Does anyone have a clever idea what I could do to unlock the screen, so that I can grab the rest of the data that's left on the phone?

Or any other way of getting to the data?

Comment: get a second Moto Z play, tape two mouses together and unlock simultaneously

Comment: @alecxs I like your thinking^^ That's a pretty cool idea, but I fear, it won't really help me^^

Comment: What do you mean with login by gesture, screen lock pattern? adb should run before unlock, at least on my phone I can unlock pattern with scrcpy. I guess it's problem with rsa keys. scrcpy comes with adb.exe which is different to platform-tools, therefore will get in conflict with existing `.android` folder (do a backup, just in case) and discard existing rsa keys inside. you will see *'adb devices'* unauthorized. another reason might be adb only enabled in MTP mode, but phones default is *charge only*

Comment: Yes, a lock pattern. I hoped, I could unlock it using a keyboard, but that sadly doesn't seem to work. On my phone, adb only starts after the screen has been unlocked. It's always been like that. After the botched repair, when the display still showed something, I could login using a mouse and after that use scrcpy. That worked fine. But I went to sleep before I could finish the backup. In the mean time the display completely died and the battery ran out. So today I tried to start it back up. The fingerprint sensor still vibrates the phone, so I know its on, but I can't get past the lockscreen

Comment: I even had the phone plugged in, so that it wouldn't run out of battery, but the case wasn't fully closed and there was a switch on the inside, that stops the phone from charging with the case opened. Stupid me did not disable the lock screen...

Comment: By any chance you can make screenshots to external MicroSD Card? That would maybe show you mouse cursor

Comment: I guess you would like the data that is in the phone, right? I'm not an expert regarding mobile software development, but I would try to take the data out building a software for it - maybe with Android Studio, which allows you to run/debug an app directly in your phone. I'm not sure it would work in your case, neither if it would be possible to do anything with a broken screen (I believe you need to have allowed the development tools in your phone for that), but I'd give it a try, since the tools for that are free.

Comment: @alecxs: That's a pretty awsome idea! I don't know if the default screenshot path is the sd card, though... But if I am lucky Google Photos might sync the screenshots.

Comment: @Leonardo Alves Machado: I considered this, but without adb I can't upload/install any software...